# "Meine Leute, DAS sind...." Why Das?

Tags: grammar-identification

In the novel I am reading a suspect says to the police "Meine Leute, das sind alles anständige Menschen, ...". My question is why does the author write "das sind" rather than "die sind"? After all "die Leute" is plural.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Es/Sie) sind starke Studenten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38728/es-sie-sind-starke-studenten)

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38793/3237

Comment: I checked these questions and I don't think they address the actual confusion here, though they may help clarify things. To the OP, it's usually a good idea to include the full sentence for context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neuter forms of pronouns have special uses. **Das** is a demonstrative pronoun in neuter in your sentence. It ignores the gender and even the number of what it refers to. You find it in copulative sentences.

> **Das** ist meine Mutter. **Das** ist mein Vater.
> **Das** sind meine Kinder.

Dudenband 4 Ausgabe 2009 Randnummer 352